# htaccess rewrite rule tweak

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website with HTTPS installed.
I need to ensure all pages (except the ones that are intentionally HTTPS) are forced to show on non-https.
The HTTPS is installed ONLY on `domain-name.com/ssl-directory/what-ever-page-goes-here/`

So, only the pages after `domain-name.com/ssl-directory/` should keep the HTTPS (they do now) and all other (including `domain-name.com/ssl-directory/` itself should be forced to non-https).

So far, this is what I've got but it's not working and as I'm not an expert with htaccess redirects, I don't know why.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ssl-directory/(.*)
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

As I said, I'm not an expert in this, but I think this should mean =>

turn `RewriteEngine` on

If `HTTPS` and

If `REQUEST_URI` is not a child of `ssl-directory`

Rewrite to same page, but with `http`

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ssl-directory(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Better to use `HTTP_HOST` instead of `SERVER_NAME` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` has a `/` at the start.

Comment: thanks for the response but when I copy this code and try to access pages that are children of /ssl-directory/ - I get redirected to the homepage... any idea why?

Comment: it was structured like this => domain-name.com/ssl-directory/some-page-title/

Comment: Can you please try this out in a different browser or clear the browser cache.

Comment: Just to let you know that I retested this code and found it to be working fine.

Comment: hm.. just did and still no luck.. I'll mark your comment as answer as I'm sure it works (since you tested it successfully).. there's probably a bug somewhere in the code... thanks

Comment: Thanks for accepting but it should have solved your issue also. 1. Is this the only code you have in .htaccess? 2. Do you have another .htaccess by chance in `ssl-directory`?